# JavaScript Popup Window via OnClick and Inline Styling

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, styles

all.

I have been dabbling around with JavaScript but I stumbled upon a problem that I am not sure how to get around. What I want to do is create a list of links that have a small fixed pop up window with a message on it.

I made a list like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <li><a href="#">google.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">espn.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">stackoverflow.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">wikipedia.org</a></li>

</body>
</html>
```

But I am not exactly sure what to do to make a pop up screen with fixed dimensions, like 100x100 and it saying something like "Hello." Is there a way to do this with inline styling and implementing the onclick function? I have tried doing this with div tags, a separate styling sheet and so on before, but I am trying to see if there are other methods of doing this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used boot box to create the alert:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".openDialog" ).on( "click", function() {
      bootbox.alert('Hello');
    });
  } );
  </script>
<body>

    <li><a href="#" class="openDialog">google.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="openDialog">espn.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="openDialog">stackoverflow.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="openDialog">wikipedia.org</a></li>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there a method to doing this without using something like bootstrap or jquery? I want to try and keep this done with Javascript directly.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, Komal! I am trying to test the code that you have provided, but when I press the links to see what the output is, the links do not create a pop up window. Is there a way around this?

Comment: right-click anywhere on the code and click on inspect, in the console tab are there any error messages?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just cleared the cache in my computer and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to bring back the question, but I got it to display properly on the browser from your fiddle, but when I try it on my editor, the code does not run properly. It just sits there as links and when I click on them, nothing happens.

Comment: have you tried saving the code on your desktop and then opening via a browser? If this works on your browser the editor has disabled java script, if it does not work in browser; right click on screen, click on inspect, and see what the error message in console tab is.

Comment: I have tried that, but for some reason it is not working. I am not seeing an error message either, which is odd.

Comment: Sorry for not updating, I managed to figure it out. I had some minor errors throughout the code while editing it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `window.open()` function. You can call it directly with an `onClick()` as you requested. You can also have full control over the dimensions.

For example, this is how you would make a window pop up that is 100 x 100 with some content inside.

First we open the window with a title MsgWindow `window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=100,height=100");`

Then we put content into the window.

```
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 100px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
```

Here is the documentation 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Hope that helps